# Is it possible to swipe the Admin card correctly on the first try?

Tags: among-us

Whenever I get the Admin card task, I spend ages trying to swipe it. I think I'm starting to nail down the correct speed for scanning it, but even still it's very finnicky - the quickest success I've been able to get is after 5 tries.

I've just found [this "glitch"?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AmongUs/comments/iz5p9n/how_to_get_admin_card_1st_try_everytime/), which will give a quick success, but it requires one to quickly swipe the card repeatedly (rather than just once). I have also heard plenty of anecdotal evidence that it's possible, but nothing conclusive.

Is it actually possible to scan the card correctly on the first try? Or is there some sort of 'minimum tries needed' to be able to get a success?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. A correct swipe is about 1/2 second at a uniform speed, slightly slower than the speed at which you would scan a card reader at a grocery store. It's admittedly easier to do on mouse (and when you're not stressed by an Impostor possibly stack-killing you).

Here's a video of a YouTuber named Alpharad swiping the card first try during a game:

Answer (score 2):

I have heard that if you swipe slowly to the arrow and then really fast to the end you will actually complete the quest, I have actually tried this myself and It actually does work.!